# On the definition of a infinite set by Tarski

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

As far as I know, Tarski's definition of infinite set is:

> A set $X$ is **Tarski infinite**, iff there exists a nonempty
>   subset $S\subset P(X)$ such that for every $A \in S$ there exists $B \in S$ with $A \subsetneq B$.

I think it is the same as the following definition.

> A set $X$ is **Tarski infinite**, iff for every $A \in  (P(X)-\{X\})$ there exists $B \in (P(X)-\{X\})$ with $A \subsetneq B$.

And similarly for finite set,

> A set $X$ is **Tarski finite**, iff exists $A \in  (P(X)-\{X\})$ s.t. there is no $B \in (P(X)-\{X\})$ with $A \subsetneq B$.

I think this is simpler. But is there a reason not to define it this way?

Comment: $\mathbb N\setminus\{0\}∈P(\mathbb N)\setminus\{\mathbb N\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition that you quote says that the set $X$ is Tarski-infinite if there is some non-empty strictly increasing chain $S$ of subsets of $X$. Your proposed equivalent definition implies that every proper subset $A$ of $X$ can be extended to a larger proper subset of $X$; but that doesn't work, because an infinite $X$ will have subsets that don't belong to any strictly increasing sequence : if you take $X = \Bbb{N}$ and $A = X \setminus \{0\}$, then there are no subsets of $X$ strictly between $A$ and $X$, but $X$ is infinite. In that example, the set $S = \{\{0\}, \{0, 1\}, \{0, 1, 2\}, \ldots\}$ gives a witness to the infiniteness of $X$ according to Tarski's definition.

Comment: I'd suggest “… if there is a non-empty ⊂-chain of subsets of  without a maximal element.”

Comment: @vladomirreshetnikov: I've added non-empty, but unless otherwise specified, the ordering we use on sets is the subset ordering and strictly increasing implies there is no maximal element, so I think my wording is now fine.

Comment: The definition of a [_chain_](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Chain.html) I'm familiar with is “a linearly ordered subset of a partially ordered set”. In this case, the poset is $\mathcal P(X)$ partially ordered by $\subset$. I'm also familiar with a definition of [_strictly increasing_](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/StrictlyIncreasingFunction.html) when applied to a function or sequence (which is a function from indices to corresponding elements). A finite sequence can be strictly increasing, according to that definition. Could you clarify what _strictly increasing chain_ means in your answer?

Comment: Sorry if I'm being too pedantic, I don't intend to be annoying.

Comment: Do you have a reference that defines a _strictly increasing chain_ this way? This seems like an unusual term usage to me. In my experience, such chains are usually described as “having no maximal element”. If I saw “a strictly increasing sequence”, I would understand it as having no decreasing or constant intervals, but not necessarily infinite.

Comment: I honestly googled it and could not find sources using _strictly increasing_ in that way. On the contrary, I found many examples like [“Every strictly increasing chain of ideals is finite.”](https://bcourses.berkeley.edu/files/70526078/download?download_frd=1&verifier=cyyn0DMfk4qSS3X1mWf8TRpw8YHbSlokGZsBY45K)

Comment: That Wikipedia article on ACC says [“no _infinite_ strictly ascending sequence”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascending_chain_condition#:~:text=no%20infinite%20strictly%20ascending%20sequence). Note that it explicitly adds _infinite_, which is circular if we are trying to define what _infinite_ means.

Comment: Regarding sequences: Wikipedia says [“Sequences can be finite, as in these examples, or infinite”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence#:~:text=Sequences%20can%20be%20finite%2C%20as%20in%20these%20examples%2C%20or%20infinite), which is consistent with definitions of a sequence in many other sources. If we were to stipulate that we mean only _infinite_ sequences, which is again circular if we are trying to define what _infinite_ means.

Comment: Oh, I'm really sorry, I didn't intend to bother or annoy you. If we assume your definition “By strictly increasing, I mean that for any $A$ in the chain, there is a $B$ in the chain that has $A$ as a proper subset”, your answer gives a perfectly correct non-circular definition of Tarski-infinitenes. I was just trying to say that this usage of the term _strictly increasing_ appeared unusual to me. Thank you for your responses, and I'm sorry if I offended you in any way. Kind regards.

Comment: And I am sorry If I sounded a bit snappy - it's been a long day. Thanks again for your comments, which have resulted in a better phrased answer and given me some useful points about terminology to bear in mind for the future. And I assure you that I was not in the least offended. My best regards to you.